# WinSCP.com Access is denied with a pre-entered password but working manually

Tags: passwords, sftp, access-denied, winscp

I am trying to write a script to automatically download a file from my sftp server. When I use the following command in `winscp.com`:

```
open user:password@sftpserver
```

I am receiving:

> Access denied.

Same password is working when I login manually.

Answer (score 1):

This is typically caused by some special character in the password that has a specific meaning in the [session URL](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/session_url).

Such characters has to be URL-encoded. For example the `@` has to be encoded as the `%40`.

See a [list of special characters that needs to be URL-encoded in WinSCP URL](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/session_url#special).

Alternatively, since WinSCP 5.19, you can use [`-username`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open#username) and [`-password`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open#password) switches, which do not need any encoding.

---

If that does not help, [enable logging](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/logging) both for the script (the `/log` [command-line switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline)) and a manual login. And compare the logs. You can also [enable password logging](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_logging) to see the actual password used for the authentication.

---

There's also an entire FAQ on WinSCP site covering [Why I cannot connect/transfer using script, when I can using GUI?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_script_vs_gui)

---

Side note: You should better specify a protocol in the URL:

```
open sftp://user:password@sftpserver
```